# SQL Nested query on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to select every space a company has where its area is bigger than average per company. Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Space outer
WHERE area >
( SELECT AVG (area)
FROM Space inner
WHERE outer.address = inner.address );
```

MySQL returns a syntax error starting at area>. I know I shouldn't have used address as primary key, and I can't use JOIN. It's just an assignment. Please, help

Comment: Use fully qualified column names to avoid ambiguity:  `WHERE outer.area` and `AVG(inner.area)`

Comment: So is there one avg or average is per company.... yet we don't know how to define company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First derive the average space across all records...

```
(Select avg(area) mavg from space)
```

This returns a single value that we can cross join to all space records and then just check for area > average.

```
Select * 
from Space
cross join (Select avg(area) mavg from space) Co
where area > Co.mavg
```

Since we know the result from the derived table/inline view will only 1 value every time, the cross join doesn't increase the number of rows being evaluated; and the rdbms only has to evaluate the average once.

However this assumes you want average across all records and not just across a company.  If it is by company... then something like...

```
Select S.* 
from Space S
LEFT join (Select address, avg(area) mavg from space Group by address) Co
  on S.address= Co.address
where S.area > Co.mavg
```

This determines the average by company joins back to space on that company and then compares each space record for the company to the company's average.

Since we don't know how you define company in terms of data, I just assumed a "address" field.

a different approach...

```
Select S.* 
from space S
where S.area > (Select avg(area) from space)
```

However this assumes average across all companies

or

```
Select S.*
from space
where s.avg > (Select avg(area) from space S2 where S.Company = S2.company)
```

If this doesn't do it I would need to see the DDL of the table space (The structure columns, data types PK, FKs etc)  and some sample data.

unless address is the same for every company area.... there's must be some other criteria to relate a company to all the other company records (a name perhaps or a consistent key?)

Personally I find the use of a correlated sub query in this case slow as it has to calculate the average for every record in Space.  The cross join IMO would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, @xQbert , but my task requires a no-JOINS nested query. I see, you're an SQL expert, can you tell me if it is possible?

Comment: Thank you @xQbert , I'll mark your answer as answered since it's correct and exhaustive. It didn't solve my problem but the only reason I see is a task flaw, so I'll need to discuss it to my college staff. Thanks.

Comment: if it didn't help don't mark it correct.  others may be able to offer different approaches.